# Quarkus test - Conditional mock external api call

Tags: quarkus

I would like to mock external api call only for specific cases during test. Otherwise real call has to be made.

**External api client**:

```
@Path("/orders")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "e2e-test-endpoint")
public interface OrderManagement {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}/status")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Uni<OrderResponse> orderStatus(@PathParam("id") String id);
}
```

**Test**:

```
@QuarkusTest
class RelatedOrderResourceTest {

    @InjectMock
    @RestClient
    OrderManagement orderManagementMock;

    @Test
    void getAll() {

        // if external api is called with param "fake-id" mocked response is returned,
        // otherwise call external api
        Mockito.when(orderManagementMock.orderStatus("fake-id"))
                .thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(new OrderResponse("VIZV", "Running")));

        given()
                .when().get("/api/v1/relatedorders")
                .then()
                .statusCode(OK.getStatusCode())
                .body("$.size()", equalTo(1),
                        "[0].trmStatus", is("VIZV"),
                        "[0].trmStatusDescription", is("Running"));

    }
}
```

Comment: What you're talking about is called _partial mocking_. Try `@InjectSpy` instead of `@InjectMock`, that should help.